# How can I get a 1D convolution in theano

Tags: python, convolution, theano

The only function I can find is for 2D convolutions [described here](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/signal/conv.html#theano.tensor.signal.conv.conv2d)...

Is there any optimised 1D function ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I believe there's no `conv1d` in theano, Lasagne (a neural network library on top of theano) has several implementations of Conv1D layer. Some are based on `conv2d` function of theano with one of the dimensions equal to 1, some use single or multiple dot products. I would try all of them, may be a dot-product based ones will perform better than `conv2d` with `width=1`.

https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/lasagne/theano_extensions/conv.py

Comment: I've just been investigating lasagne. It's a great library! I've been struggling a little, being new to theano, with the syntax required. I think Lasagne could be useful in guiding me through that area!

Answer (score 4):

It looks as though this is [in development](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/issues/2028).
I've realised I can use the `conv2d()` function by specifying either width or height as 1...

For the function `conv2d()`, the parameter `image_shape` takes a list of length 4 containing:

```
([number_images,] height, width)
```

by setting `height=1` or `width=1` it forces it to a 1D convolution.

Comment: This is actually exactly what lasagne does in their conv1d layer: https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/blob/master/lasagne/theano_extensions/conv.py

Answer (score 3):

Just to be a bit more specific, I found this to work nicely:

```
conv2d = T.signal.conv.conv2d

x = T.dmatrix()
y = T.dmatrix()
veclen = x.shape[1]

conv1d_expr = conv2d(x, y, image_shape=(1, veclen), border_mode='full')

conv1d = theano.function([x, y], outputs=conv1d_expr)
```

`border_mode = 'full'` is optional.